# sudo -Si bash script, how to provide argument?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have something like below, it's simply running a bash script which looks for an arg $1. However this doesnt work:

```
echo MyPassWord | sudo -Si "script.sh arg1"
```

I get an error akin to script.sh arg1, file not found. Note that if I take out arg1, then script runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proper usage of sudo is:

```
sudo -Si script.sh arg1
```

(without the double quotes)